# Populate dropdown using json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I need to know how to populate a dropdown using the JSON object.. 
Im using php to send json to the client.. client catches the json data using ajax. 
i use below code to check what i exactly receive from the server.

```
  var test = xmlhttp.responseText;
  alert(test);
```

the result was showing me.. as below...

```
   {"2":"pricelist.xml","3":"camera.xml", "4":"cd.xml","5":"data.xml"}
```

what i exactly do is.. i have set of xml files on the server im reading those filenames using php  and i convert it to json object using json_encode and then i send that ot the client to populate the dropdownlist using the json data which i send from server. I have no issue in receiving the json data in client side as i tested above. i need to know how do i populate the data using above json data

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155467/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-and-ajax-not-working-in-anything-new

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML

```
<select id="myselect">
</select>
```

The javascript(Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/))

```
var json={} // Populate this json object
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    $('#myselect').append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
});
```

Comment: i tried above code. it does not seem to be working.. here is my code where i catch the json obj that comes from the server. `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
      var test = xmlhttp.responseText;
      AddFiles(test);
        }
    }` i have placed ur code inside the AddFiles function.

Comment: Have you included jQuery on you page. Put this tag in your head section, to be safe make this tag the first one among others. `<script type='text/javascript' src= 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits, I think I have got it right this time :P. One more caveat, in the 3rd line make sure to reference your select by id. I have updated the above answer according to that.

Comment: `src= 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'` this line was missing before. now i added that one as well. but yet it does not work.. :( seems bad luck for me :( am i making any other mistakes?

Comment: What you get from server as a response is JSON text and not an object. You need to parse the text into a JSON object. Have you parsed the text like this `var test = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);`