# Why is my select list not populating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to populate a select list with items from my database. I have confirmed (with the use of an "alert()" box) that the jquery .getJSON function is fetching the correct data, but the select list is still not populating.

```
var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
$.getJSON('optionGrabber.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, dbValue) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value",dbValue);
        selectBox.appendChild(option);
    });
});
myDiv.appendChild(selectBox);
```

Like I said, when I stick an "alert(dbValue);" immediately after the ".each" statement, I get the correct data in the alert pop-ups.

Comment: Have you checked your code with firebug ? do you get any error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: @Farshad No errors in Firebug.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but you're mixing up jQuery with Vanilla Javascript. Why don't you follow a standard? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/p38vu1x8/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I didn't want to use jQuery at all, but I figured I could use this little bit to help me out.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Nothing wrong with using jQuery with Vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's exactly what I said.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155467/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-and-ajax-not-working-in-anything-new) may be useful for your case

Comment: My optionGrapper.php is returning '["one","two","three","four","five"]' (minus single quotes). I am assuming this is correct, no? I am using json_encode() on the PHP side, and I was assuming that, since the alerts were displaying the proper information, that jQuery was decoding the JSON properly. However, I added an array and used .each on that and the select populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add value without using the setAttribute method like this:

```
var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
$.getJSON('optionGrabber.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, dbValue) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = dbValue;
        option.text = dbValue;
        selectBox.appendChild(option);
    });
});
myDiv.appendChild(selectBox);
```

Added the text to the option as well

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ncgdtuh/)

Comment: This is a nice feature, but my drop-down is still not populating.

Comment: @Brian: added a working fiddle...maybe a problem elsewhere...can you show the data in dbValue

Answer (score 0):

I think to initialize the value it should be:

```
option.value = dbValue;
```

per [w3Schools reference for javascript and option](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp). I think I encountered this once myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here might be that your not setting the text option? So they are being added but you can't see them?

```
option.text = dbValue;
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. Using Firebug, the JavaScript creates the "select" element, but does not add the options.

Comment: I created this fiddle dummying some of your data: http://jsfiddle.net/ruv5mycy/ Might help?

Comment: Following your example, I added an array and used .each on that and the select populated correctly. My optionGrapper.php is returning '["one","two","three","four","five"]' (minus single quotes). I am assuming this is correct, no? I am using json_encode() on the PHP side, and I was assuming that, since the alerts were displaying the proper information, that jQuery was decoding the JSON properly.

Comment: I have update Fiddle to use that array and it works okay. That's what you get if you log 'data' to the console before the .each()?

Comment: Yes. I even check the size of the array returning from my optionGrabber.php and it is correct.

Comment: optionGrapper.php on a URL the fiddle can call?

Comment: Yes it is. Like I said, the "alert()" can display the options correctly, they just aren't getting appended to the selectBox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60264/discussion-between-stuart-miller-and-brian).

Comment: What happens if you use 'key' instead of 'dbValue'?